# Replacement for GL_LUMINANCE, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA​

Tags: image, opengl, opengl-3

For memory-efficient realtime embedded graphics I have traditionally used DDS images encoded using `GL_LUMINANCE` when I need lossless grayscale images (or `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` when there is alpha needed). However, I have just discovered that these file formats were [deprecated in OpenGL 3](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Legacy_Image_Formats) and removed from 3.1.

Is there a replacement image format for lossless grayscale-only data that is 8 bits per pixel or less (or 16bpp when alpha is involved)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you scroll up a bit on that wiki page you'll see `GL_RED/GL_R*` and `GL_RG*` for 1- and 2-channel images.

[`glTexImage2D()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml):

> `GL_RED`: Each element is a single red component. The GL converts it to floating point and assembles it into an RGBA element by attaching 0 for green and blue, and 1 for alpha...
>
> `GL_RG`: Each element is a red/green double. The GL converts it to floating point and assembles it into an RGBA element by attaching 0 for blue, and 1 for alpha...

[As GuyRT pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076814/replacement-for-gl-luminance-gl-luminance-alpha/20076950#comment29910382_20076950) if you have `EXT_texture_swizzle/ARB_texture_swizzle` and/or OpenGL version >= 3.3 you can use [swizzle mask](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask) to expand out/rearrange your texture color components.

Comment: Are these semantically equivalent, such that a `GL_RED` should always be interpreted by a shader to replicate the values across RGB, and `RG` should always use the green/second channel for alpha?

Comment: No, you'll have to expand them out yourself in the shader.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: is it considered official (or at least commonplace) that a shader reading from `GL_RED` should always expand the values across green and blue? Or is this basically shoe-horning the explicit meaning of `GL_LUMINANCE` into the implementation of `GL_RED`?

Comment: I don't think there's a convention, official or otherwise.

Comment: You can also use swizzling, so that your shader sees the values as luminance/alpha - have a look at: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask

Comment: Are `GL_RED` and `GL_RG` available for older OpenGLs too?

Comment: @yairchu: [`GL_RED` is](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml), but not `GL_RG`.